# Misspelled Option - Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I am trying to set the options for the editor in an external file outside of my HTML file. I have everything imported and I can change the options from within the HTML script but when I try in the external file I get the error misspelled option "enableLiveAutocompletion". I've attached some code snippets below:

main HTML file:

```html
<script src="/editor/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/editor/ext-language_tools.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="module" src="src/js/main.js"></script>
code.js file (imported through main as a module)
```

```js
ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
this.session = ace.createEditSession("// Edit Session " + name);
this.session.setOptions({
        enableLiveAutocompletion : true
 })
```

If anyone could provide some insight that would be great.

I have tried creating the session in the HTML file and it works fine. Although when I try to do it externally I get that error.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Could you also post the full error stack?

Comment: The error is "misspelled option: enableLiveAutocompletion"

Answer (score 1):

`enableLiveAutocompletion` is an option for the editor, not session, set it when you call `ace.edit`